# How can I set position of 3 UITable and 2 Navigation Bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4, frame

My XIB has 3 UITable and 3 Navigation bar.UITables are dynamic scale and I use navigation bar to seperate UITable and show title of UITable name.

I want to set first navigation bar under the first table and second navigation bar under second table.

I try to find frame of first table to get position x,y and height of table but it don't work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    blah blah...
    CGRect table1frame = table1.frame; //But it don't work
}
```

I don't know where to get each table frame.
please help me or guide me.Thank you very much

Comment: please print NSLog(@"Table 1 : %@",table1); in above method, if this print UITableView object details on screen then we really have problem but it it prints null then please make  sure you have connected table1 with outlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but keep in mind that the geometry of the view controller's view (its bounds) is not yet set when `viewDidLoad` is called.  The bounds (and frames) of any subviews have not been set either.  That means that all frames are pretty much set to zero at this point.  And, that may be what you are noticing if you are trying to access the view's frame, or the frame of any of its subviews,

So, if you need to do anything based on the view's geometry (on its frame or the frame of any of its subviews), it is generally done in `viewWillAppear`.

Your problem may not be *where* to get the table view's frame, but *when* to get it.  You are looking for it in the right place (the table view's frame property), but you are too early.  I hope this is helpful.

Comment: First I'm sorry for my wrong grammar ;(.And second Yep I'm looking at when am I get table view's frame. Thank you very much.I will try as soon as possible

Comment: Umm I try - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CGRect table1frame = table1.frame;
    NSLog(@"Test position %@", NSStringFromCGRect(table1frame));
}   But It's first size before I change size of cell by put text in cell.

Comment: @crazyoxygen: if you change the size of the cell later, the table view frame shouldn't change.  There will just be fewer cells in the table view.  Is this what you're concerned about?  Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.Yes there will be fewer cell in table if the cell is bigger that first set.That I must be resize table.But I don't know how.And after I resize table that can show all cell.I must put navigation bar under table cell and that again I don't know How can I put navigation bar cause I don't know How I get last frame of table.please help me :(

Comment: You can resize any view (including table view & navigation bar) and place it where you want just by setting its frame.  'view.frame = CGRectMake(... )'  I only wonder what kind of UI would require you to be moving table views and navigation bars around the screen.  Maybe it's not worth the effort, and it may make for a confusing user experience.  You might be better off just setting all the frames (table views & navigation bars) in 'viewWillAppear' and not moving them again.  But, as mentioned, if you do want to move them, just reset the frame any time.

Comment: here is my sample xib >>> http://img807.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110430at122.png/  <<< please take a look.Each table has dynamic cell and I just use navigation bar to show title.Or I should set header of table2&3 Bigger and set name ?? I try to NSLog @viewWillAppear but it still first my table CGRect not last CGRect that table resize by dynamic cell.please help me or guide me.

Comment: Again, a dynamically changing cell should not change the frame of the table view.  So, I don't see the problem.  Anyway, setting a header sounds like a better way to go than using navigation bars.  Just set the headerView property of the table view to a custom view that you create.  You can set its frame with respect to the table view & it will stay in place even if the table view's frame changes.  You can add a UILabel as a subview, as well as any other subviews, to customize any way you like.  That should solve all your problems.